# Efficient way to get entire rows with MAX(id) when grouping by a foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-9.5

Consider tables A, B and C. B and C are related to A through a foreign key, and there are many Bs and Cs with the same A foreign key.

Suppose the following query:

```
SELECT
  A.pk AS pk_a,
  MAX(B.id) AS new_b,
  MAX(C.id) AS new_c
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON B.fk_a = pk_a
INNER JOIN C ON C.fk_a = pk_a
GROUP BY pk_a
```

I would like to retrieve the entire new_b and new_c rows from B and C for each `GROUP BY pk_a`.

Surely I could wrap this as a subselect and `JOIN B ON b.id = new_b`, and the same for C, *but* B and C are huge and I would like to avoid this.

I could also use `SELECT DISTINCT ON(A.pk) A.pk, B.*, C.*` and `ORDER BY A.pk, B.id, C.id`, but that would only guarantee the latest B.*, not the latest C.*.

Is there any other way I'm missing?

Comment: Since `B and C are huge`, performance is an issue. To optimize, we need more information: How many rows in A, B and C? How many rows from A are referenced in B and C respectively? I suspect *many* related rows in B and C for one row in A?

Comment: BTW: column names in the example is inconsistent: `A.pk` <> `A.pk_a`. (The join clause cannot reference the column alias  `pk_a`, only the source column name `pk`. Two answers copied this mistake, which makes them equally incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For *few* rows (like 2 or 3 or 5 on avg., depends) in `B` and `C` per row in `A`, `DISTINCT ON` is typically fastest.

For *many* rows per row in `A`, there are (*much*) more efficient solutions. And your information: *"B and C are huge"* indicates as much.
I suggest `LATERAL` subqueries with `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`, backed  by a matching index.

```
SELECT A.pk AS pk_a, B.*, C.*
FROM   A
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT *
   FROM   B
   WHERE  B.fk_a = A.pk  -- lateral reference
   ORDER  BY B.id DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) B ON true
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT *
   FROM   C
   WHERE  C.fk_a = A.pk  -- lateral reference
   ORDER  BY C.id DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) C ON true;
```

Assuming `B.id` and `C.id` are `NOT NULL`.

You *need* at least indexes on the FK columns. Ideally, multi-column indexes on `B (fk_a, id DESC)` and `C (fk_a, id DESC)` though.

Use **`LEFT JOIN`**! to not exclude rows from `A` that are not referenced in either `B` or `C`. It would be an evil trap to use `[INNER] JOIN` here, since you join to two unrelated tables.

Detailed explanation:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Related:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

#### Simpler syntax with smart naming convention

The result of above query has `pk_a` once and `fk_a` twice. Useless ballast - and the same column name twice may be an actual problem, depending on your client.

You can spell out a column list in the outer `SELECT` (instead of the syntax shortcut `A.*, B.*`) to avoid redundancies. You may have to do that either way if there are more duplicate names or if you don't want *all* columns.

But with a smart naming convention, the `USING` clause can fold the redundant PK and FK columns for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM   A
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT * FROM B
   WHERE  B.a_id = A.a_id
   ORDER  BY B.id DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) B USING (a_id)
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT * FROM C
   WHERE  C.a_id = A.a_id
   ORDER  BY C.id DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) C USING (a_id);
```

*Logically*, `USING (a_id)` is redundant here, since `WHERE  B.a_id = A.a_id` in the subquery already filters the same way. But the additional effect of `USING` is that joining columns are folded to *one* instance. So only *one* `a_id` remains in the result. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN)

> Furthermore, the output of `JOIN USING` suppresses redundant columns:
>   there is no need to print both of the matched columns, since they must
>   have equal values. While `JOIN ON` produces all columns from `T1` followed
>   by all columns from `T2`, `JOIN USING` produces one output column for each
>   of the listed column pairs (in the listed order), followed by any
>   remaining columns from `T1`, followed by any remaining columns from `T2`.

It also typically makes a lot of sense to use the same name for the same data. So: `a_id` for PK *and* FK columns.

Comment: The simple(r) `(fk_a, id)` indexes would be sufficient, because of backwards index scans, aren't they? Though the `(fk_a, id DESC)` indexes are good enough, but why complicate their directions?

Comment: @pozs: Yes, reverse index scan is *almost* as fast in Postgres - generally. So a plain index is typically good enough for both directions. But for *certain* applications of ***multicolumn*** indexes, the order per column does matter (including this one). See: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/39599/3684  And since adding `DESC` (or even `DESC NULLS LAST`) means no complications other than adding the key words, I would highly recommend it if that's the typical order you need.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are asking for?

```
SELECT abc.*
FROM (SELECT A.pk AS pk_a, b.*, c.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.pk ORDER BY b.id DESC) as seqnum_b,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.pk ORDER BY c.id DESC) as seqnum_c
      FROM A INNER JOIN
           B
           ON B.fk_a = pk_a INNER JOIN
           C
           ON C.fk_a = pk_a
     ) abc
WHERE seqnum_b = 1 or seqnum_c = 1;
```

Actually, I think the above is on the right track, but you probably want:

```
SELECT a.pk, b.*, c.*
FROM A INNER JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT ON (b.fk_a) b.*
      FROM b
      ORDER BY b.fk_a, b.id DESC
     ) b 
     ON B.fk_a = pk_a JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.fk_a) c.*
      FROM c
      ORDER BY c.fk_a, c.id DESC
     ) c
     ON c.fk_a = pk_a;
```

In Postgres 9.5, you can also use lateral joins for a similar effect.

Comment: Thanks. I tested the second alternative, seems okay, just submitted a minor edit to correct a few typos.

Comment: I think there might be some kind of typo around `b INNER JOIN ON`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  A.pk AS pk_a,
  MAX(B.id) OVER(PARTITION BY pk_a) AS new_b,
  MAX(C.id) OVER(PARTITION BY pk_a) AS new_c
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON B.fk_a = pk_a
INNER JOIN C ON C.fk_a = pk_a
```

Comment: You may have missed *"get entire rows"* in the title and the body of the Q.